# Jessie : Cannot install Java due to wrong tzdata version

Tags: debian, apt, dpkg

I wanted to install a JRE on my debian server (a sheevaplug) and got this :

```
$ sudo apt-get install default-jre
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 default-jre : Depends: default-jre-headless (= 2:1.7-52) but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: openjdk-7-jre (>= 7~u3-2.1.1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I narrowed down the problem to be with the tzdata package.

The installed version is the **wheezy** version (2015g-0+deb7u1) instead of the **jessie** version (2015f-0+deb8u1).

The server is several years old and has been upgraded from squeeze to wheezy, then to jessie.

For some reason, the package never upgraded.
(May be because the wheezy package is version 2015g, while the jessie is "only" 2015f)

How can I solve my dependency problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After downloading the package from Debian and manually installing it with dpkg, I managed to install the JRE.

```
wget http://ftp.fr.debian.org/debian/pool/main/t/tzdata/tzdata_2015f-0+deb8u1_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i tzdata_2015f-0+deb8u1_all.deb
sudo apt-get install default-jre
```

Comment: See the jessie-updates answer above/below - installing a deb blindly may work, but you're likely to either miss out on updates in the future or have other problems....

Answer (score 0):

You're probably missing jessie-updates from your /etc/apt/sources.list - try adding :

```
deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie-updates main
```

and apt-get updating etc.

Comment: I have that in my sources.list : `deb http://ftp.fr.debian.org/debian/ stable-updates main contrib non-free`, that's probably not the cause. Anyway, thanks for the answer :-)

Comment: I can add a pointless: "I had what appeared to be the same problem and it fixed it for me....(dependencies broken by a missing tzdata-java package)". 
The Jessie version of tzdata and tzdata-java package is 201**6**f-0+... by the way.